# repeat an image in background desktop applications

Tags: c#, desktop-application

As we do in website design, take 1px of an image and repeat that image in x or y direction using CSS. Is this possible to do with C# desktop applications.

After searching I found **tilebrush** but it seems to be for WPF only. My question is can we do the same in desktop applications without WPF? Please make me clear.

**Guys better to make comments what is wrong with the post so that I can edit rather than to give negative mark for the post**. Please tell me what is wrong with my question.

Comment: how are you drawing the image ? using winforms ?

Comment: Why don't you just change the background colour?

Comment: @polisha989: I am drawing the image using photoshop. But keeping the whole image as background is burden for the server. So I want to cut 1px from the image and repeat it in the background. Similar we do in webdesigns, I hope you are familiar with this design practice for websites.

Comment: _I hope you are familiar with this design practice for websites._ Huh, 1x1 was a spacer, way back in the 90s. Why don't you tell us what you really are trying to do?

Comment: Please check this link :: http://www.1x1px.me/
and try the solution given below. You will know what I want to do. Guys please remove the negative marks.

Comment: @TaW  **1x1 was a spacer, way back in the 90s.** You still in 90s it is 2015. the age of html5 and CSS3. Hope you are familiar with web designs concpets. Please think before comments.

Answer (score 3):

In properties of your form (hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the properties panel) set `BackgroundImage` to the selected image and `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Tile`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. let me try and will reply you.

Comment: hello guys I also found a link which will provide 1*1px image. Hope it will be useful for you also [http://www.1x1px.me/]

Comment: Please try this ::  http://www.1x1px.me/

Comment: Why would one even want a 1x1 'image' ??

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski :: did the link work? Please reply.